# Does Angular inline predicates in views?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say we have the following template:

```
<div ng-if="!ctrl.someVar && (ctrl.someOtherVar || !ctrl.someThirdVar)">
  ...
</div>
```

The condition is ugly and verbose, so we could put it in a predicate function on the `ctrl` object:

```
ctrl.somePredicate = function() {
  return !ctrl.someVar && (ctrl.someOtherVar || !ctrl.someThirdVar);
};

<div ng-if="ctrl.somePredicate()"> ... </div>
```

This reads much better, but according to what I know about angular this means that functions in view templates have to be called every digest cycle, whereas the inline expressions would only change when any of the values in the expression change. But if the function is a simple predicate like that above, is angular "smart enough" to only call it when the variables the predicate depends on change? If so, under what circumstances does this optimization happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no is not. What you can do is add a $`watch` expression, and only use one single variable in your `ng-if` expression. Something like this:

```
//In your scope:
function updateExp() {
  $scope.myExp = !$scope.someVar && ($scope.someOtherVar || !$scope.someThirdVar);
}
$scope.myExp = initVal;
$scope.$watch('someVar',updateExp);
$scope.$watch('someOtherVar ', updateExp);
$scope.$watch('someThirdVar', updateExp);
```

And in your template:

```
<div ng-if="myExp"> ... </div>
```

that way is more cleaner in the view but at the cost of one more variable in your scope, and 3 more watchers